# Qt и Ubuntu, перемещение курсора в терминале

Tags: c++, linux, c, qt

Имею простейшее приложение(консольное), написанное в Qt и в ОС Ubuntu 14.xx.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTextStream _cin(stdin);
    int aa = 0;
    _cin >> aa;
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно, в чем проблема: когда я окончил ввод числа, я решил его редактировать и переместить курсор на пару символов назад, чтобы удалить одну единицу. Перемещение осуществлял стрелками на клавиатуре. Однако, вместо перемещения получил это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить именно перемещение стрелки на символ назад? Просто в терминале это работает.

Comment: Прям так напрямую не получится, вам нужно будет написать что-то типа эмулятора терминала видимо. Посмотрите вот здесь: [вопрос на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7543313/3503216)

Comment: @vegorov ну ничего себе..пока ждал ответа, узнал про ncurses. Стоит ли оно того? Вроде бы она позволяет сделать желаемое, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @Range ncurses, в вашем случае, избавит от необходимости использовать qt. Если вам не нужна графическая составляющая, а только текстовый интерфейс, то curses хватит с головой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже приступил к написанию велосипеда, однако случайно узнал о [GNU Readline](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_23.html)
Данная библиотека используется в большинстве программ, написанных для ОС Linux, и предоставляет все нужные возможности управления терминалом, в том числе решая мою проблему.

Answer (score 3):

Получится только стереть или нажать комбинацию CTRL+C or CTRL+Z и запустить программу заново